# Is there a way to get a spinner DatePicker on Android in 2021

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker, datepickerdialog

I've got a DialogFragment class implemented just like how google says in their Picker documentation.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers

However the ability to set it to spinner mode as described here doesn't seem to work no matter what I do.  Apparently the Material date picker doesn't support that anymore.. But I'm pretty sure DatePickerDialog instantiates the DatePicker shown below.. which says it supports spinner mode.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/DatePicker

Here's my DialogFragment.. literally a copy from google
And then I've tried referencing the datePicker object from the DialogFragment class..

```
class MyDatePickerDialog : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val dialog = DatePickerDialog( requireActivity(),this, year, month, day )

        //
        // I've tried these and they do nothing
        //
        dialog.datePicker.spinnerShown = true
        dialog.datePicker.calendarViewShown = false
        dialog.datePicker.datePickerMode = "spinner" <-- this isn't even valid


        return( dialog )
    }

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
       //Do something here
    }
}
```

Then I've also tried setting these values through the theme
styles.xml

```
    <style name="DatePickerSpinner" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
        <item name="android:calendarViewShown">false</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerShown">true</item>
    </style>
```

theme.xml

```
...
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerSpinner</item>
...
```

And I verified the style was being used by the datepicker by changing some colors on it.  I'm not sure what else is pertinent.  Is this possible at all in 2021?  Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, there are [lots of date and time picker libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created).

Comment: You can do it by using theming. I answered this same question a couple weeks ago, asked by someone named YellowClock. I’m on mobile and can’t search for it right now.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've tried to do it with theming as shown.  I'm fairly new to how the whole theming system works so if you could point me to a specific example with details, when you get a chance, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Nvm, found your example and followed it exactly, and it worked.  Crazy you can't just add the item in the main theme.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70071690/kotlinhow-to-make-a-popup-date-pick-when-click-the-edittext/70073080#70073080

Comment: Yes, theming is really complicated if you want to do more than changing the basic colors. Glad it helped!